# Is there any way for the video background to be transparent on al OS and browers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, daisyui

I just publish my portfolio website. In that on the home screen I have used a animated animoji video.

Now the issue here is, in some browser and OS the video background show black color.
I have attached 2 images for reference.

Tech Stack - Nextjs, TailwindCSS, DaisyUI, and Typescript.

This is what I implemented -
Here's the code for it -

```html
<video ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted loop className="w-full h-full lg:w-2/3 object-cover">
          <source src="/assets/Animoji.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```

I also tired using different libraries such as react-player, video-react, etc.

Let me know if anyone knows a workaround for this, its making the home page look bod.
Thanks in advance.

[Window/Chrome Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hVsJ.png)

[MacOS/Brave Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIYur.png)

Comment: according to https://rotato.app/blog/transparent-videos-for-the-web you'll have to have videos in supported formats for each browser ("Safari supports HEVC with alpha, and Chrome does not. Chrome supports VP9 with alpha, and Safari does not."). Or you build a page that doesn't rely on quirky features :)